# Skipped TestNG test case count is wrong while running test cases using Maven command

Tags: java, maven, testng

I am using `mvn clean test` to trigger the TestNG test cases for my automation framework.
I have implemented TestNG test retry mechanism in the framework. I have intentionally failed one test case to check the mechanism. When i used the maven command the skiped test case count is displayed as O instead of 1
TestNG version-7.5
Maven version-3.6.3
Jdk version -8

Comment: Which surefire plugin version? How does your pom look like? How does your test look like?

Comment: @khmarbaise I was using 2.19.1 and it was updated to 3.0.0-M6 . After the update the count is correct.